# Are we a little stingy about upvoting questions?

Tags: discussion

I felt like questions with accepted answers were upvoted less often here than on other SE sites, so I decided to have a look at the Data Explorer:

```
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where Score > 0 and CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --35
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --116
```

So, about **30%** of questions with accepted answers were upvoted recently. I compared this with some of my other SE sites.

Here's Electrical Engineering SE:

```
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where Score > 0 and CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --359
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --748
```

which is about **48%**.

Here's Science Fiction and Fantasy SE:

```
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where Score > 0 and CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --378
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --391
```

which is **97%**.

Here's StackOverflow:

```
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where Score > 0 and CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --31594
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --85569
```

which is **37%**.

Here's Data Science SE:

```
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where Score > 0 and CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --40
select count(distinct Id) from Posts where CreationDate > '2017-07-01' and AcceptedAnswerId is not null; --75
```

which is about **53%**.

So, we're a little bit on the low side. I wonder why this is?

I'm a noob here myself, but I'd like to see more activity in the Arduino SE.  I just figure that if a question is good enough to be left open and receive an answer, with the OP active and polite enough to accept the answer, then in most cases giving the OP a little encouragement with an upvote on the question would help to encourage more participation.

Also, this was a good excuse to play with the Data Explorer :)

Comment: Do you have a link to the Data Explorer that you could share? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sa_leinad Sure https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This isn't necessarily a bad thing - consider for example IoT SE, where no matter how bad a question is or irrelevant to what was asked an "answer" is, it will get several upvotes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I see your point

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Great use of the Data Explorer!

---

I've noticed that, in general, reputation creeps up fairly slowly here, compared to some other sites. I've got a lot more reputation for a handful of answers elsewhere (eg. English Learners SE) than I do for the same number of answers here. Quite often an answer isn't upvoted **at all**.

I think this is partly because of a mentality of:

- I have a problem in my code, I'll ask here on Arduino SE
- I've got my answer, kthxbye!

A while ago I was posting comments under answers along the lines of:

> If this helped you please up-vote it, and even *accept* the answer. This helps others know that the answer works.

---

You can help too by up-voting answers when you see them pop up (if you think they deserve it). I look for questions that *Community* (the system) has brought back to the first page, because no-one has accepted the answer, or voted for it. If the answer looks helpful, I vote it up. This helps stop old questions bobbing up all the time, and also helps other users know that someone thought the answer was OK.

It also helps give the person who answered some rep, which will help them get more [privileges](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) from Stack Exchange (like being able to delete answers, etc.)

Comment: I 100% agree with everything you said here but I would like to point out that the topic was about upvoting questions rather than answers.

Comment: Oops! *slaps self*

Comment: I think good/correct answers not being accepted is a bigger problem, because it left lot of questions as *unanswered", which not true. I don't see how upvoting a question serve any purpose at all, because how many up-votes a question got it's not a criteria for anything.

Comment: "I don't see how upvoting a question serve any purpose at all". @Look Alterno, reputation points bestow privileges that allow users to more effectively participate in improving content. If someone is consistently asking good questions then they would likely also do a good job of reviewing other user's questions. Getting that sort of user up to the reputation points required for these privileges certainly has the potential to benefit Arduino Stack Exchange.

Comment: *how many up-votes a question got it's not a criteria for anything* - it is, though. Say you do a search for "working" and sort by votes, then the most up-voted question appears at the top. So, out of a set of questions which might ask similar things, the most up-voted question can be selected as the best question "of this sort". This can help you select the "best" question which might ask something you want to know, which also hopefully will have good answers.

Comment: @Nick Different people have different search habits. I search with Google, not inside Arduino.SE, so I don't see *upvotes*. And, like many, I only look at first page results.

Comment: Regardless of your search habits, the up-votes have a meaning on the site. That was my point.

Answer (score 5):

I think one factor is that we simply get a higher percentage of low quality questions here that are unclear, don't provide enough information, or are poorly formatted. We may eventually badger the author or edit enough to make the question upvote worthy in the end but by that point I don't feel the need to reward the author.

I suppose a better approach would be to simply evaluate the question as-is without regard for the history.

I do think this makes it even more important to upvote the high quality questions we do get.

Comment: Regarding that, some people on this site rarely *ask* questions, but usually *answer* them. For example, [Majenko](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/4143/majenko?tab=questions), who has the highest rep currently, has answered *1,795* questions! But he has asked *no questions!* You (per1234) have asked no questions. So voting your questions up isn't going to encourage you. :)

Comment: Low quality questions often don't get great answers, and even when they do, may not attract future visitors who benefit from and upvote those  answers.

Answer (score 2):

I have to confess I often upvote the question I answered, even if I don't like it that much. Every upvote helps a question hit the HNQ list, which means every answer to it will earn much more reputation that it would otherwise. I know it's pretty much rep chasing (frankly, I don't like HNQ), but those are the rules which are set, and if someone doesn't use them for their advantage, it's their loss.

Answer (score 0):

Every community creates its microculture influenced by a handful of alpha users who tend to develop a clique and impose a standard of behavior and quality evaluation.

Arduino community doesnt seem as humble and nurturing as most SE communities.  One user, for example, compares arduino users to stubborn, ignorant horses in his personal description.

IMO, every answer should AUTOMATICALLY award an irreversible upvote to the question it answers.

Comment: It bothers me too that there aren't enough upvotes on Arduino SE. I am yet to come up with a good solution. One thing that doesn't work in our favour is that we have so many new users every day who ask their question, get an answer and then never stick around to pay it forward. And because they are in and out they don't read/learn the guides that SE is founded on, resulting often in poor questions. The users who do stick around are great. But we all could put more effort into upvoting (me included). You are right in that we can change the culture by leading by example.